# Discord bot does not start, but i dont get any issues

Tags: python-3.x, discord.py

Bot isnt running when i print python3 bot.py in console, but i dont get any issues

console only write python. Whats wrong?

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

intents = discord.Intents.all()

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix = '!',intents=intents)

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print("ready")


@client.command()
async def hello(ctx):
    await ctx.send("Hello")
```

Comment: You missed `client.run('your token here')`. Check the [documentation](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/quickstart.html) for more info.

Comment: @FelixFourcolor i write `client.run('token')` but any changes. I create bot using this video "How to make a Discord Bot in Python! (Part 1: Setup)" by James S, and bot istn running when i write python3 bot.py in console

Comment: Did you forget to substitute `'token'` with the real token, by any chance?

Comment: Also the process to set up the bot and link to the server is a bit tricky, just make sure you follow every step. Other than that I don't know what to say.

Comment: @FelixFourcolor ok i'll try. Thanks. And i put the right token

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to call client.run(token)

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

token = "token"

intents = discord.Intents.all()

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix = '!',intents=intents)

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print("ready")


@client.command()
async def hello(ctx):
    await ctx.send("Hello")

client.run(token)
```

Comment: i put this but any changes

Comment: Try now, I forgot to change one variable name from bot to client and that's why it won't start.